# check whether a sigma-algebra is countably generated

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the Borel algebra $\mathcal{F}$. Define an equivalence relation $x\sim x'$ if $x$ and $x'$ only differs on finitely many places, i.e.~$|\{n: x_n\neq x_n'\}|<\infty$. Let $\Pi$ be the associated partition on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Let $\overline{\Pi}$ denotes the algebra generated by $\Pi$ closed under *arbitrary* unions. I would like to know whether the sigma-algebra $\overline{\Pi}\cap\mathcal{F}$ is countably generated. In general I am curious if there is any general procedure of checking whether a sigma-algebra is countably generated.

Comment: We have $\Pi \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and so $\sigma(\Pi) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}$ and so $\sigma(\Pi) \cap \mathcal{F} = \sigma(\Pi)$.  This is true whenever $\mathcal{F}$ is a (sigma) algebra that includes all countably-infinite subsets of sequences.

Comment: @Michael Sorry my bad. I made a typo. I was thinking of not $\sigma(\Pi)\cap\mathcal{F}$ but $\overline{\Pi}\cap\mathcal{F}$, where $\overline{\Pi}$ denotes the algebra generated by $\Pi$ closed under arbitrary unions. I have amended my question accordingly.

Comment: What is a "Borel algebra for $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$"? Is it also a sigma-algebra?   Does $\{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...\} = \{1, 0, 0, 0, ...\}$ in the same way that $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} 2^{-i} = 2^{-1}$? What precisely is meant by an "algebra generated by $\Pi$ closed under  arbitrary unions"?

Comment: @Michael Sorry I should have clarified: the Borel algebra on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the algebra generated by cylinder sets of the form $B^n_x=\{y: y^n=x^n\}$ where $x^n$ is the initial $n$-segment of $x$ (e.g.~is $x$ is the constant $0$ string, then $B^1_x$ denotes the set of all strings that start with $0$). The sigma algebra $\overline{\Pi}$ is the collection of arbitrary unions of elements in $\Pi$.